# QNetworkAccessManager is not sending data part of POST request

Tags: qt, http-post, qnetworkaccessmanager

When sending POST data to server, from Qt application looks everything good but data part of HTTP part were not sent. In Wireshark in POST packet is visible correct "Content-Length" value but size of whole HTTP segment is only about 226 bytes (is independent on POST data size).

I can't find reason why data part is not send. Any idea?

The application is running in console. A complete source is below.

project.pro:

```
QT += widgets
QT -= gui
QT += network

CONFIG += c++11

TARGET = POSTrequest
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QUrl>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("http://www.server.com/index.php"));
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    QNetworkAccessManager manager;
    QNetworkReply *reply = manager.post(request, "a=aaaaaa");

    QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &a, SLOT(quit()));

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Can you post your whole function or main where this is happening? It might be possible that manager is going out of scope or something. Here is what it says about the data being sent: `data must be open for reading and must remain valid until the finished() signal is emitted for this reply.`... So what happens after manager.post(...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me on both OS X and Windows:

```
#post-request-36549732.pro
QT = core network
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
TARGET = post-request-36549732
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

```
// main.cpp
#include <QtNetwork>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    QCoreApplication a{argc, argv};
    QNetworkAccessManager manager;
    QByteArray post{"a="};
    post.append(QByteArray{512, 'b'});
    QNetworkRequest req(QUrl("http://server/test.php"));
    req.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    // Must be a queued connection, or else the multi-threaded manager might
    // win the race and signal quit before `a.exec()` starts running. In such
    // case, the `quit()` is a NOP. We don't want that.
    QObject::connect(&manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, &a, [](QNetworkReply * reply){
       qDebug() << reply->errorString();
       qApp->quit();
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);

    manager.post(req, post);
    return a.exec();
}
```

You might be interpreting your Wireshark data incorrectly. Make sure you're looking at the Reassembled TCP aspect of the HTTP request. Here's how it looks for me; server is 192.168.2.1:

[image: wireshark capture screenshow]

Comment: Thank you for your help. You are right, I was wrong with Wireshark - filtered only POST requests and POST data were sent in another packet [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU], so I didn't see that. (My version of code works as well.)